# Average rows with same first column

Tags: text-processing, awk, perl

Given a file with two columns:

```
Id  ht
510 69
510 67
510 65
510 62
510 59
601 29
601 26
601 21
601 20
```

I need a way to coalesce all rows with the same ID into one that has an average height. In this case, (69 + 67 + 65 + 62 + 59) / 5 = 64 and (29 + 26 + 21 + 20) / 4 = 24, so the output should be:

```
Id  Avg.ht
 510 64
 601 24
```

How can I do that using sed/awk/perl?

Comment: Are the same ids grouped together as shown in the sample?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using awk :

The input file

```
$ cat FILE
Id  ht
510 69
510 67
510 65
510 62
510 59
601 29
601 26
601 21
601 20
```

Awk in a shell :

```
$ awk '
    NR>1{
        arr[$1]   += $2
        count[$1] += 1
    }
    END{
        for (a in arr) {
            print "id avg " a " = " arr[a] / count[a]
        }
    }
' FILE
```

Or with Perl in a shell :

```
$ perl -lane '
    END {
        foreach my $key (keys(%hash)) {
            print "id avg $key = " . $hash{$key} / $count{$key};
        }
    }
    if ($. > 1) {
        $hash{$F[0]}  += $F[1];
        $count{$F[0]} += 1;
    }
' FILE
```

Output is :

```
id avg 601 = 24
id avg 510 = 64.4
```

And last for the joke, a Perl dark-obfuscated one-liner =)

```
perl -lane'END{for(keys(%h)){print"$_:".$h{$_}/$c{$_}}}($.>1)&&do{$h{$F[0]}+=$F[1];$c{$F[0]}++}' FILE
```

Answer (score 2):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my %sum_so_far;
my %count_so_far;
while ( <> ) {
    # Skip lines that don't start with a digit
    next if m/^[^\d]/;

    # Accumulate the sum and the count
    my @line = split();
    $sum_so_far{$line[0]}   += $line[1];
    $count_so_far{$line[0]} += 1;
}

# Dump the output
print "Id Avg.ht\n";
foreach my $id ( keys %count_so_far ) {
    my $avg = $sum_so_far{$id}/$count_so_far{$id};
    print " $id $avg\n";
}
```

Output:

```
ire@localhost$ perl make_average.pl input.txt 
Id Avg.ht
 510 64.4
 601 24
```

Note that your sample output is wrong. There's no way you can get an average of 52 when every value for that id is 59 or larger.

Also, you have a letter `l` in one of your columns, masquerading as the number `1`...

Answer (score 2):

With `gnu` [`datamash`](https://www.gnu.org/software/datamash/):

```
datamash -H -s -g 1 mean 2 <file
```

```
GroupBy(Id) mean()
510 64.4
601 24
```

This `s`orts and `g`roups by `1`st field calculating `2`nd field `mean` value, preserving `H`eaders. It assumes the fields are separated by single tab. Use `-W, --whitespace` if they're separated by multiple blanks or `-t, --field-separator=` to define another field separator (space, comma etc). Since `datamash` requires sorted input, the output will be sorted by the grouped column.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at what is done here: http://www.sugihartono.com/programming/group-by-count-and-sorting-using-perl-script/

The essential difficult part is doing a 'group by' operation.
The linked script does that using a hash.

In that link they are calculating the sum, but getting the average will not be far different.